# Regex to match two parts of a url

Tags: regex, url

This is my first question for Stackoverflow... apologies in advance if I break a rule in asking a question. I have searched for my question and was not able to find anything related to what I'm looking for, and I have read through the question posting guide...

I am trying to create a RegEx pattern which will match two parts of a URL.

Example URL:

app.company.com/base-path?parameter1=stuff&parameter2=morestuff&parameter3=IMPORTANT%20THING

In this case I want the pattern to match in the case that there is a base path and the third parameter, so both:
***/base-path*** and all of ***parameter3=IMPORTANT%20THING***

Any help would be appreciated! Please let me know if I can provide more info...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer, and you can test that [here](https://regex101.com/)

```regex
/^.+?(\/.+?)\?.+?&(parameter3=.+)$/gm
```

I do not know which language you use, this is PCRE2 version which is used for PHP 7.3+, but I think it is easy to migrate to other language.

### Security risk

There are some risk when using regex, for that bad guys can construct malicious `parameter1` or `parameter2` to spoof regex and you will get unexpected result, especially **AFTER DECODING URL**.

For example url

```
app.company.com/base-path?parameter1=stuff&parameter2=%26parameter3%3Dmorestuff&parameter3=IMPORTANT%20THING
```

Bad guys set `parameter2=%26parameter3%3Dmorestuff`, and after decoding, you will get this url

```
app.company.com/base-path?parameter1=stuff&parameter2=&parameter3=morestuff&parameter3=IMPORTANT THING
```

And what you get from regex is `parameter3=morestuff&parameter3=IMPORTANT THING`, which is unexpected.

So, if you really want to use regex, **DO NOT DECODE URL BEFORE MATCHING**

Comment: Thanks for your support! This is really helpful and a great start. Also thank you for the Security tips, I will keep that in mind!

I suppose I failed to clarify that I would be looking to specifically match the /base-path (similar to how you've done it with Parameter 3)... 


So the regex would match:
app.company.com/base-path?parameter1=stuff&parameter2=morestuff&parameter3=IMPORTANT%20THING

But it wouldn't match:
app.company.com/different-base-path?parameter1=stuff&parameter2=morestuff&parameter3=IMPORTANT%20THING

Comment: I was able to work it out with some additional time spent after clicking your link!